# [iPhone]Have a way (or library) to create .doc files in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, doc

Have a way (or a library) to create .doc files in iPhone app ?

Answer (score 2):

Short of writing your own library, you have two choices:

- Use [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), which will produce a Word-readable document that covers basic word processing features.
- Send the data to a server, have the server do the conversion, then return the Word document to the application.

Comment: @hungbm06 Sorry, no.  Keep in mind that this is a question and answer site, not a freelancer site.