# How to create/generate .docx files in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am working on Editing of .docx & .doc files & for editing I am using webview.When user complete his editing I picked-up all HTML content from webview & try to replace html  tags with .docx tag.Now this is not good way to generate .docx/.doc files from Webview.Does any one has any idea except above how I  generate .docx files ???

Comment: Read this [post][1]. It have the answer of your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999831/iphonehave-a-way-or-library-to-create-doc-files-in-iphone-app

Comment: When you say `webview`, is this a native iOS application or a HTML app?